# Do equal rational integrands imply equal integrals, save for a constant?

Tags: integration, logarithms

Specifically, when integrating  $\frac{1}{ax+b}$  we get  $\frac{1}{a}\ln|ax+b|$.

However, if we multiply the integrand by say $c/c = 1$, then the integral computes to   $(1/a)\ln|c(ax+b)|$. Can someone please explain why this is so or where my error may be?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you forgetting $+C$?  Observe that $\ln|c|/a$ is a constant.

Comment: Ah ha. Thanks Michael!

Answer (score 0):

We have $$\int\frac{1}{ax+b} \, \mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{a}\ln{|ax+b|} + k$$

Whilst $$\int \frac{1}{ax+ b} \cdot \frac{c}{c} \, \mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{a}\ln{ |c(ax+b)|} + k' = \frac{1}{a}\ln |c| + \frac{1}{a}\ln{|ax+b|} + k'$$

We need only take $k = k' + \frac{1}{a}\ln |c|$ to verify that both solutions are identical up to an additive constant.